# how to use round robin method in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i am trying to create a sub array from an array.i.e; think I have an array such as given below

```
 $array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19}
```

which I **explode** and assign it to a variable $i..
and run the for loop as shown below..

```
for ( $i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    $a = array();
    $b = $array[$i];
    for($j=0;$j<count($array);$j++){
        if($b != $array[$j]){

            $a[] = $array[$j];
        }
    }
```

the output I want is when

```
$i = 1
```

the array should be

```
{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
```

and when

```
$i = 2
```

the array should be

```
{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
```

similarly when

```
$i=19
```

the array should be

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

so how can I do it.

Comment: You do understand that the $a and $b values will be over-written on each iteration of the loop...?

Comment: Can you explain that criteria a little bit?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I dint get you

Comment: I mean can you let us know a little about that criteria that you have. How should the output be deduced?  For example when i is 1 then why should it go only upto 11 and not to the end of the array? Without knowing the criteria its really guesswork

Comment: If you're trying to implement round robin for tournament scheduling you're going to run in to problems taking this approach

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `$i` is supposed to be an offset and not the actual value in the array, you can do

```
$fullArray = range(1, 19);

$i = 19;
$valuesToReturn = 10;

$subset = iterator_to_array(
    new LimitIterator(
      new InfiniteIterator(
        new ArrayIterator($fullArray)
      ),
      $i,
      $valuesToReturn
   )
);

print_r($subset);
```

This will give your desired output, e.g.

```
$i = 1 will give 2 to 11
$i = 2 will give 3 to 12
…
$i = 10 will give 11 to 1
$i = 11 will give 12 to 2
…
$i = 19 will give 1 to 10
$i = 20 will give the same as $i = 1 again
```

and so on.

Comment: does this assume the array range to be in order ? Also its quite nice.. Show off ;]

Comment: @Pogrindis no, the `LimitIterator` works on the `InfiniteIterator`'s offset to determine the items in the subset. The subset will be returned in the same order as in `$fullArray`, incl. keys. That will also work for associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($i + 10 < count($array))
        $a = array_slice($array, $i, 10);
    else
        $a = array_merge(array_slice($array, $i), array_slice($array, 0, 10-(count($array)-$i)));

    // do something with $a before it is over-written on the next iteration
}
```

This test:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($i + 10 < count($array))
        $a = array_slice($array, $i, 10);
    else
        $a = array_merge(array_slice($array, $i), array_slice($array, 0, 10-(count($array)-$i)));

    echo "<h2>$i</h2>\n<pre>".print_r($a,true)."</pre><br />\n";
}
```

Resulted in this:

```
0

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
...
9

Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 13
    [4] => 14
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 16
    [7] => 17
    [8] => 18
    [9] => 19
)

10

Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 14
    [4] => 15
    [5] => 16
    [6] => 17
    [7] => 18
    [8] => 19
    [9] => 1
)
...
18

Array
(
    [0] => 19
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

Comment: Although i did not down-vote but can you tell us how this will create 10 element chunks of that array everytime?

Comment: You're right - either the question was edited or I didn't read carefully enough. Answer edited...

Answer (score 2):

This works fine from my end

```
<?php
    $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19);

    $size = sizeof($array); // Defining the array size

    $str = 17; // This is the reference value from which you have to extract the values

    $key = array_search($str, $array);

    $key = $key+1; // in order to skip the given reference value
    $start = $key%$size;

    $end = $start+9;

    for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++) {
        $j = ($i%$size);
        $result[] = $array[$j];
    }

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = range(1, 19);

$i = 19;
$result = array();
$after = array_slice($array, $i, 10);
$before = array_slice($array, 0, 10 - count($after));
$result = array_merge($after, $before);

var_dump(json_encode($result));
```

P.S. please note 0 element has 1 value and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Round-robin on an array can be achieved by doing a "rotate" operation inside each iteration:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
    // rotate the array (left)
    array_push($array, array_shift($array));
    // use $array
}
```

During the loop, the first element of the array is placed at the back. At the end of the loop, the array is restored to its original value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need is a slice of a certain size from the array, slice that wraps around the array's end and continues from the beginning. It treats the array like a circular list.

You can achieve this in many ways, one of the simplest (in terms of lines of code) is to extend the original array by appending a copy of it at its end and use the PHP function [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract the slice you need:

```
function getWrappedSlice(array $array, $start, $count = 10)
{
    return array_slice(array_merge($array, $array), $start, $count);
}
```

Of course, you have to be sure that `$start` is between `0` and `count($array) - 1` (including), otherwise the value returned by the function won't be what you expect.